# пуш изменений в ветку main git/github, синхронизация веток

Tags: git, github

Ситуация такая. Мы работаем с командником над одним проектом. И изначально договаривались, что в гитхабе у нас будет ветка main (финальная версия кода, который идет на деплой), ветка dev, куда сливаются рабочий код через pull request, и + у каждого своя ветка. НО все пошло не так, я работала в своей ветке и сокомандник тоже, но он свои изменения запушал напрямую в main. И теперь в main старый код + его новый код, в dev - старый код, а в моей ветке  - старый код + мой новый код.
Вопрос такой: как правильно синхронизировать все ветки? чтобы ничего не потерять.
Мне нужно подтянуть из main в dev и потом в свою ветку его код и потом свой код пушать? или и я пушаю свои изменения в свою ветку потом pull request в dev и main, но тогда будут потери?

Comment: Сначала можете подтянуть изменения из main в dev. На этом уже можно сказать всё встало на свои места. Далее эти изменения можете как подтягивать к себе в ветку, так и не делать этого, если они вам не нужны. Потом просто сделаете PR в дев из своей ветки.

Comment: Пусть *сокомандник* уберет из main свой код, переложит его на правильную ветку, все запушит, а вы потом продолжите работать, как обычно.

Comment: Также можете настроить правила, чтобы хотя бы без одного апрува нельзя было лить изменения в дев/main

Comment: ребейсните ветку от нового маин

Comment: @user7860670 Как именно рекомендуете убрать свой код из main?

Comment: Переставить ветку `main` на последний правильный коммит. (исправление общей истории подразумевает forced push)

Comment: А в целом рекомендую ознакомиться с уже придуманными подходами к ведению веток, например
https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow